# Disable observer/property until record is saved

Tags: ember.js

All my model properties are observed in default by Ember, so when I'm creating new record in form, my application is updating all places where model is used (posts counter, header with title etc.),

I don't want behavior like this until my record is valid and saved in database.

Controller:

```
ProManager.TasksNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  headerTitle: 'Create'
  buttonTitle: 'Create'

  actions:
   save: ->
     if @content.validate()
     @content.save().then (=>
       @transitionToRoute('task', @content)
     ), (error) =>
       @content.becameError()
    else
      @content.set('errors', @content.get('validationErrors.fullMessages'))
```

Template:

```
<form id="task-form">
<fieldset>
    <div>
        <label {{bindAttr for="titleField.elementId"}}>Title</label>
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='title' name='title' viewName='titleField'}}
    </div>
    <div>
        <label {{bindAttr for='descriptionField.elementId'}}>Last Name</label>
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='description' name='description' viewName='descriptionField'}}
    </div>
    <a href='#' {{action save}} class='btn btn-success'>{{buttonTitle}}</a>
</fieldset>
```

I don't want to update/display {{title}} or {{description}} on page until saved:

Thanks for help :)

Here's a nice example: http://jsbin.com/arebem/2/edit,
When creating new user, first_name is updated on the user's list before save.

Ok, I have some kind of solution for this, we can show it only when it's not dirty.

```
{{#unless isDirty}}
<div class="accordion-on">
    <h3>#{{id}} {{title}}</h3>
    <div>
        <div>{{title}}</div>
        <div>{{description}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
{{/unless}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution template #1

```
{{#unless isDirty}}
<div id="task-lists" class="well">
    <h5>#{{id}} {{title}}</h5>
    <button class="btn btn-small" {{action 'openModal' 'TasksNew' this 'Task' }}>New Task</button>

    {{#each task in content.tasks}}
        {{ render "tasks/show_accordion" task }}
    {{/each}}
</div>
{{/unless}}
```

Solution template #2 (setting hidden css class if not saved)

```
<div {{bind-attr class=":accordion isDirty:hidden"}}>

<h3>#{{id}} {{title}}</h3>
<div>
    <div>{{title}}</div>
    <div>{{description}}</div>
</div>
</div>
```